# Netty sendBufferSize receiveBufferSize bootstrap options

Tags: java, netty

Could you explain me the idea behind sendBufferSize receiveBufferSize options that are used together with bootstrap:

```
bootstrap.setOption("sendBufferSize", 1048576); 
bootstrap.setOption("receiveBufferSize", 1048576);
```

I noticed they can improve performance of the following code when big-size data is transferred between clients:

```
// encode method in OneToOneEncoder subclass -> 1st client
ChannelBuffer buffer = ChannelBuffers.buffer(capacity);
buffer.writeInt(myData);

// decode method in FrameDecoder subclass -> 2nd client
int myData = buffer.readInt();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These options specify the buffer sizes on the Channel's underlying Java [Socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/net/Socket.html) instances.
There is a good summary of what those mean in [What are SO_SNDBUF and SO_RECVBUF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257410/what-are-so-sndbuf-and-so-recvbuf).