# Increasing SO_RCVBUF vs more UDP receiving port (For UDP tuning)

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp, winsock

One common way to improve UDP throughput is to increase the SO_RCVBUF buffer size. This means the datagram is delivered and lies in the kernal memory.

Theoretically, can this also be achieved by opening multiple UDP ports and have the client send the data to different ports?

Can the answer be true for Linux and Windows?

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/a/4476788/1212012 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/4257961/1212012, both OS handle `SO_RCVBUF` the same: it's the memory per socket. But how your client will know which port is free to receive data?

Comment: In my case, i could ask the client to sent to different ports. X clients to port1, and y clients to port2.