Server end get stuck for a while when receiving udp packets using socket
I am trying to receive 6000 udp packets sent by my client end on server end, while it seems to get stuck after receiving around 4000-5000 packets and receive the remaining packets after about 30-40 second. It happens both to high entropy data packets(with random content) and low entropy data packets(with all zeros), except it gets stuck at packet number of approx. 80 and never receives the following packets for high entropy data packets.
server.c
    char buffer[payload_size];

    int nBuf = 32*1024;
    int s = setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, (const char*)&nBuf, sizeof(int));
    if (s < 0) {
        perror("SO_RCVBUF");
        free(cf);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    printf("receiving low entropy packets\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < packet_num; i++) {
        //memset(&buffer, 0, payload_size);
        bzero(buffer, payload_size);
        int n = (int) recvfrom(sockfd, buffer, payload_size, MSG_WAITALL, 
            (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &cli_addr_len);
        printf("i: %d\n", i);
        if (i == 0 && n > 0) {
            low_start = clock();
        }
    }
    memset(buffer, 0, payload_size);
    low_end = clock();

    sleep(1);
    printf("receiving high entropy packets\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < packet_num; i++) {
        memset(&buffer, 0, payload_size);
        int n = (int) recvfrom(sockfd, buffer, payload_size, MSG_WAITALL,
             (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &cli_addr_len);
        printf("i: %d\n", i);
        if (i == 0 && n > 0) {
            high_start = clock();
        }
    }
    high_end = clock();


client.c
    char buffer[payload_size];
    memset(&buffer, 0, payload_size);

    int nBuf = 32*1024;
    setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, (const char*)&nBuf, sizeof(int));
    

    for (int i = 0; i < num_packets; i++) {
        buffer[0] = (char) ((i >> 8) & 0xFF);
        buffer[1] = (char) (i & 0xFF);
        printf("i: %d\n", i);
        if (sendto(sockfd, buffer, payload_size, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr,        sizeof(server_addr)) < 0) {
            perror("failed to send udp packet, low entropy");
            free(cf);
            close(sockfd);
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    printf("low entropy packets sent\n");
    sleep(interval_time);

    char random[payload_size];
    get_random_byte(payload_size, random);
    for (int i = 0; i < num_packets; i++) {
    random[0] = (char) ((i >> 8) & 0xFF);
        random[1] = (char) (i & 0xFF);
        printf("i: %d\n", i);
        if (sendto(sockfd, random, payload_size, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr,            sizeof(server_addr)) < 0) {
            perror("failed to send udp packet, high entropy");
            free(cf);
            close(sockfd);
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    printf("high entropy packets sent\n");


I was thinking the buffer was filled and it wasn't cleaned up in time, but it didn't seem to make the server end more efficient.

The order you receive UDP packets in isn't necessarily the order they're sent in, and they can be silently dropped and never received.

@Shawn I feel that is the problem, I think I will just ignore dropped packets and exit loop if timeout.

BTW, SO_RCVBUF isn't setting the size of a datagram allowed to be received; it's telling the kernel how much space to allocate for queuing incoming packets you haven't yet received. You're setting it to 32K, which is smaller than the default on most platforms. You may want to experiment with setting it higher (possibly much higher) to reduce dropped packets. (See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/4476788/1076479)
